# error: conflicting types for built-in function ‘tolower’ [-Werror]

Tags: c, gcc

I have a small RTOS which does not use `glibc` and I have written own functions (e.g. `tolower`) in string.c

When compiling I am getting the error:

```
common/string.c:11:6: error: conflicting types for built-in function ‘tolower’ [-Werror]
```

Is there a CFLAGS to fix this?

Update Answer: use -fno-builtin

Comment: `-Wno-error` would do.

Comment: -fno-builtin is the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tolower` is a function from the C library and its identifier is a reserved identifier for use as an identifier with external linkage, even if you don't include the header where it is declared.

You could get rid of the warning by using `-fno-builtin` but the best is simply to chose another name for `tolower`.

> (C99, 7.1.3p1) "All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses (including the future library directions) are always reserved for use as identifiers with external linkage."

Comment: -fno-builtin is what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: The answer is not `-fno-builtin`, the answer is do not use a reserved identifier.

Comment: why not, if you are implementing your own os kernel then why not.

Comment: @mSO in that case why are you using a different type for `tolower` function? `tolower` prototype is `int tolower(int);` but the warning you get shows you are using a different type.

Comment: int is probably the wrong type for tolower. if using ASCII only.

Comment: @mSO, if you are are implementing your own OS kernel and don't want to rely on the C library provided by your compiler environment, you are in a so-called "freestanding" environment. Special rules apply here, and in particular you'd have to convince your compiler to place itself in that mood. How to do that is different from compiler to compiler, gcc has `-ffreestanding` for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using the C standard library for some reason, I won't tell you that's probably a bad idea. Even though the builtin function will probably implicitely link to a libc implementation under certain circumstances beyond your control.

Anyways... Either don't use `-Werror`, or append `-Wno-error` or fix your function to look like [the real thing](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/tolower.html):

```
int tolower(int c);
```